# Spring sts with websphere

Tags: websphere

I'm trying to switch over from IBM rational application developer to spring STS.

One of the first things I've noticed is that when I try do define a websphere server runtime library it doesn't list websphere application servers and hence I can't import a websphere library . I also noticed that it doesn't accept websphere (in my case websphere 5.1) as a targeted runtime.

Is it possible to do these two things in Spring STS?

Also, if it's not possible in spring STS does anyone reccommend an alternate IDE that might suit the job better?

Thanks

Comment: what version of Eclipse are you running STS?

Comment: I'm using Spring STS Version 3.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: You could than try adding WebSphere tools from eclipse market to your setup as you're probably using Eclipse Juno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution is installing the [IBM WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-v80-developer-tools#.UUtDyVckRtM) eclipse plugin.

An alternative is using [MyEclipse Blue](http://www.myeclipseide.com/blue/) which still supports some older WAS versions.

However for the WebSphere 5.1 you are out of luck. Noone supports this 8 year old piece of software anymore. You should really have a serious look at upgrading your WebSphere installation or migrating to a different newer application server.

**Update**

Hmm. Just figured they still list WAS5x support. However I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: thanks for that information. I hadn't heard of MyEclipse Blue. It looks like it costs though. So if I go with that one I might as well get my company to buy a license for RAD. But then again RAD might cost a lot more. I haven't checked out the cost for RAD yet.

Comment: Looking at https://www-112.ibm.com/software/howtobuy/buyingtools/paexpress/Express?part_number=D54NBLL%2CD54N4LL%2CD54SDLL%2CD59WALL%2CD59WCLL%2CD54SDLL%2CD0BHXLL%2CD0BHYLL%2CD0BHZLL%2CD0DJULL%2CD0DJWLL%2CD0DJZLL%2CD0DK1LL%2CD59VSLL%2CD54LILL%2CD59V7LL%2CD54LALL%2CD54S7LL%2CD0BI2LL%2CD0BI0LL%2CD0BI1LL%2CD54N4LL%2CD0BHXLL&catalogLocale=en_US&Locale=null&country=USA&PT=html&TACTICS=%26S_TACT%3D%26S_CMP%3D%26brand%3D&ibm-submit=Ready+to+buy the RAD starts at 2350 USD compared to 160 USD. If you only need the WAS adapter ....